# Unable to update Anaconda Packages

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am saving a set of algorithms as a Python script and discovering some warning while testing the script.  The development went fine from a designated Python environment that I created for my Data Science project; however, when I ran the script from the command line, the default anaconda libraries are being applied and those warnings are showing-up.  I tried to run a conda update --all on the Anaconda installation but the same warnings are displayed when I run the Script.

Is there a way to upgrade the Anaconda3 packages to get rid of the warning?  here is a list of warnings:

```
C:\>python retention_model.py unseen_employee_data.csv predictions.csv final_model.pkl True True
```

The code works and the prediction file is created; however, I am not sure these warnings are a good idea when I start calling this script on larger data sets.

Here is what I am getting:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.preprocessing.data module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.preprocessing. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.preprocessing is now part of the private API.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:318: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator StandardScaler from version 0.21.3 when using version 0.22.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.ensemble.forest module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.ensemble. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.ensemble is now part of the private API.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.tree.tree module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.tree. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.tree is now part of the private API.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:318: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator DecisionTreeClassifier from version 0.21.3 when using version 0.22.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:318: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator RandomForestClassifier from version 0.21.3 when using version 0.22.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:318: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator Pipeline from version 0.21.3 when using version 0.22.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)

I:\DataScience\Elite Data Science\Corner Stone#4 - Chief People Officer>python retention_model.py unseen_employee_data.csv predictions.csv final_model.pkl True True
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.preprocessing.data module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.preprocessing. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.preprocessing is now part of the private API.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:318: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator StandardScaler from version 0.21.3 when using version 0.22.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.ensemble.forest module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.ensemble. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.ensemble is now part of the private API.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.tree.tree module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.tree. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.tree is now part of the private API.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:318: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator DecisionTreeClassifier from version 0.21.3 when using version 0.22.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:318: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator RandomForestClassifier from version 0.21.3 when using version 0.22.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:318: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator Pipeline from version 0.21.3 when using version 0.22.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
```

Comment: _the default anaconda libraries are being applied_ That's an issue, right?

Comment: That is correct; the Environment that I created does not generate the warnings because the libraries/packages are all the latest versions that works with the Intel DAAL libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this issue resolved by reinstalling Anaconda.
I first renamed the anaconda3 folder from ProgramData.  downloaded the latest version of Anaconda (64bit) and installed it for All Users, checking both boxes to register the Environment Variables.  the, I navigated to the default folder, following a deactivation of the base environment.  Ran the conda update --all command to get the default environment fully updated.  Finally, I recreated my favored environment by following this post:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60953581/how-to-install-a-working-intel-data-science-environment-with-graphviz
```

Once I was done, I ran the command from my saved script and received a clean return prompot without errors or warnings.